# Websocket weird latency over local network

Tags: node.js, ssl, networking, websocket, latency

I was experimenting with live audio streaming between a browser and a nodejs server over local network and experienced some delay. I was expecting this since it's a *"heavy"* job, so I tried to pass some simple data and measure the normal delay.

Here is where it becomes strange.

```js
// server.js

const https = require('https')
const WebSocket = require('ws');

const websocketListener = (ws) => {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log(`At ${Date.now()} received ${message} latency ${Date.now() - +message}`)
  });
}

const httpListener = (req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/' && req.method === 'GET') {
    return fs.createReadStream('./index.html').pipe(res)
  } else {
    res.end('NOT found')
  }
}

const server = https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('./server.key'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./server.cert')
}, httpListener)

new WebSocket.Server({server}).on('connection', websocketListener);

server.listen({ host: '192.168.1.12', port: 1338 })
```

```html
// index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    const socket = new WebSocket(`wss://${location.host}/`);

    socket.addEventListener('open', function(event) {
      setInterval(() => {
        socket.send(Date.now())
      }, 100)
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Accessing the page on the same computer gives me almost every time `0 latency` which is somehow expected.

Now accessing the page with a mobile phone (on the same wifi) gives me at average `498 latency`. Almost half a second to pass data, which simply (in my mind) doesn't make sense. I think it should be far lower...

Accessing the page with a windows laptop (again on the same wifi), gives `-1422 latency` which simply is weird!

#### Possible problems *(that I can think)*

- SSL certificate adds latency
- Wrong measurement method
- `Date.now` is unreliable

Comment: How are you measuring the latency?  You cannot trust that `Date.now()` will be exactly the same on all three systems or even close enough to use it to measure with.

Comment: Also, you have an https connection so there could be significant differences in how a client verifies an https certificate (which may not stay only on your local network).

Comment: If you have a single client test server, how about you just log on the server when the http request arrives and then log again when the webSocket connection request arrives and when the webSocket data arrives.  Use the server-side `Date.now()` for all three logging events.  Then, you can supplement that info with the debugger network timeline in the Chrome browser so you can see the exact relative timings on the client-side of things.

Comment: Date.now is unreliable when used on different systems. To measure latency: send Date.now() from server to client; then send it back from client to server and calculate (Date.now - OLD Date.now) / 2 on the server side.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I didn't now that `Date.now` is unreliable like this, it explains a lot. Any suggestion how to measure this correctly? @jfriend00 I would like to avoid accessing debugger on android chrome if possible! @Radar155 Although it is valid, it seems not very accurate, any other suggestion for better measurement?

Comment: If you do a Google search on measuring client/server latency, you will see thousands of articles and various techniques.  This is a non-simple, but well researched topic.  You shouldn't be surprised that `Date.now()` is identical on every single system.  We don't have every single clock synced within a few milliseconds of each other.

Comment: @alex-rokabilis my solution could be not very accurate but you are just looking for an (expected) near 0 latency in a local area network. I mean, your original problem was delay with audio. Then you start debugging by measuring latency, obtaining expected near 0 latency when using the same machine but when you swiched to different machines on the same network and you noticed too much high delays. If with my solution you will find near 0 latency in other machines too, you can back to your original problem and exclude the bad network latency problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments of the question it seems that `Date.now` is unreliable between different systems. Two computers are not going to have the same time ( in milliseconds resolution ).

As a workaround to get an estimate of the latency I used this code. (Again, with the help of the question's comments)

```js
// server.js

const websocketListener = (ws) => {
    setInterval(() => {
        ws.send(Date.now())
    }, 100)
    ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log(`Latency ${(Date.now() - +message) / 2}`)
    });
}
```

```js
// index.html

socket.addEventListener('message', (msg) => {
  socket.send(msg.data)
})
```

Basically server sends its timestamp to client and then client sends it back. 
Then server simply subtracts current time with the one in the message and then divides by 2.

That way I get approximately `5ms latency` between mobile and computer (in the same wifi) which makes sense.